# stateTime vs refetchOnMount to avoid refetch on each component mount

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a request which I run when the component is mounted, what I want is to avoid this request running in each of the component re-mounts. I have reviewed the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery) and I have found two possible solutions, `stateTime: Infinity` and `refetchOnMount: false`, with both options I get the component to only run the request once, I want to know the pros and cons of each option or if there is any option that I have not taken into account that fits better for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set `staleTime` to `Infinity`. Please take a moment to read the docs on important react-query concepts, such as `staleTime`: [React-Query Important Defaults](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/important-defaults)

Having the request run again after a little while for validation should be perfectly fine. If you mutate anything in the backend with your request, use [mutations](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations).